# How do I auto click an options drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code that I have. It does select the option, but it does not click on it. I need it to click on the option or it will not work with the rest of my script. Any way of actually simulating a click?

```
//Country
function setOption(selectElement, value) {
    var options = selectElement.options;
    for (var i = 0, optionsLength = options.length; i < optionsLength; i++) {
        if (options[i].value == value) {
            selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

setOption(document.getElementById('billCountry'), Co);


//State
function setOption(selectElement, value) {
    var options = selectElement.options;
    for (var i = 0, optionsLength = options.length; i < optionsLength; i++) {
        if (options[i].value == value) {
            selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

setOption(document.getElementById('billState'), Sa);
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: no that is a variable. It works. I just want to know if I can simulate an actual click.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is in the rest of your script and you may want to consider changing it to not rely on a click. Consider using a "change" event.  If you really need to fire a click event something like this should do it:

```
var element = document.getElementById('foo');
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e.initEvent('click', true, true);
element.dispatchEvent(e);
```